# How triple ANDs ("&& &") work?

Tags: c++, logic

I have the following as an example:

```
C[i] = A[i] && & B[i-1 : i-10]
```

I understand how the short circuit logic double ANDs work, but I get confused by adding another AND to make it a triple.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: This is not valid C++. The `i-1 : i-10` part, specifically.

Comment: And, in this case assuming C++, the third ``&`` has nothing to do with the first two. ``&&`` is logical AND, and then ``&`` is 'address of''.

Answer (score 3):

The third `&` is an address-of operator, it returns a pointer to the object on its right. Since a pointer to an existing object will always be non-NULL, it will always evaluate to `true` in a boolean expression; the whole expression could be simplified to just `(bool) A[i]` and give the same results.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid C++ syntax,

```
B[i-1 : i-10] ??
```

Single & means address-of operator or bitwise AND operator
Double & i.e. && means logical AND